# When I hover fast in two links with drop down they instantly come out at the same time

Tags: jquery, html, css, css-transitions

Here is HTML code

```
<div class="nav">
    <ul class="nav-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Accounts
            <div class="dropdown" >
                <ul class="dropdown1">
                    <li><a href="#">SDM</li>
                    <li><a href="#">HB</li>
                    <li><a href="#">Teacen</li>
                    <li><a href="#">TalkNQ</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">About us
            <div class="dropdown" >
            </div>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and here is my CSS code

```
.nav {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: grey;
}
.nav-menu {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
}
.nav-menu > li {
    width: 100px;
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
    margin-left: 20px;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 30px;
}
.dropdown {
    width: 280px;
    margin-left: -90px;
    position: relative;
    height: 220px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
    display: none;
    background-color: grey;
    border-bottom: 1px solid black;
    border-left: 1px solid black;
    border-right: 1px solid black;
}
```

and my jQuery code and it is very simple.. I tried many times, but this is far as I know how to animate my drop down list

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("li").has(".dropdown").hover(function () {
        $(this).find(".dropdown").stop(true).fadeIn(300);
    },
    function () {
        $(this).find(".dropdown").delay().fadeOut(100);
    });
});
```

Comment: What is your issue? What is expected behaviour? Describe them...

Comment: Please visit the [tour] and the [help]. Before posting use the [checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to make sure your post is up to our standards.

Comment: when i hover it in accounts and about us link. fast.. the second drop down which is about us link is blocking the drop down of first link (Accounts)